# Find a better query and LINQ for improvement

Tags: performance, linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

From the following SQL Server 2008 R2 query I am trying to find:

customers and his or her orders who has placed certain products in the order details table.

This product must be matched from a cross reference table.

The query is also looking into another table (activations) and if it finds any order id in there, then it ignore them.

Here is my query:

```
Select O.CustomerId, O.OrderId
from Orders O 
    inner join Customers C
        on O.CustomerId=C.Customerid
where O.orderid not in
(
    Select orderid 
    from activations
)
and OrderId In
(
    Select orderid 
    from  Orderdetails
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        select * 
        from  OrderActivationCrossRef
        Where Orderdetails.productId=OrderActivationCrossRef.productId
    )
)
```

Can this query be improved and what will be the equivalent for LINQ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change your 'where orderid not in' and 'OrderId in' to inner joins. And make indexes on Order.CustomerId,Orderdetails.productId,OrderActivationCrossRef.Orderdetails

Answer (score 1):

The exact variable names will depend on how your context is set up, but your overall LINQ query should turn out to be something like this:

```
from o in ctx.Orders 
from c in o.Customers
where !o.Activations.Any() &&
    o.Orderdetails.Any(d => d.OrderActivationCrossRef.Any())
select new {o.CustomerId, o.OrderId}
```

Comment: Based on Hogan's answer below, will this be the best way to go, still?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql

```sql
Select O.CustomerId, O.OrderId
from Orders O 
    inner join Customers C on O.CustomerId=C.Customerid -- forces items that exist in customers
    left join activations a on a.orderid = O.orderid
    join orderdetails d on d.orderid = O.orderid  -- forces only items that exist in details
    join OrderActivationCrossRef c on d.productId = c.productId  -- forces only items that exist in crossref
where 
  a.orderid is null -- forces items that don't exist in activations
```